# How to give turtles directional commands when moving along a drawn out network?

Tags: netlogo

I want turtles to be able to flow along the paths I have drawn out for them. To do this I think it might be a reasonable idea to have a list in the u.i that allows the user to select a preordained direction of movement for that patch so the turtles know how to flow along the network. Has anyone else produced a model with this feature? If so would it be possible to give an example of the relevant source code for implementation into my own project?

Comment: You ordinarily don't need to precalculate the paths is network is not too big. Just use one of popular graph path search algorithm. Many algorithms are already implemented.

Comment: I am building a road network as part of my simulation project, I think this will be very important to achieving that end.

Answer (score 1):

I did something a while back where each patch had a direction variable  that turtles set their heading to when on the patch.

Something like

```
patches-own[dir]

to go
ask turtles [set heading dir fd .1]
end
```